# Is there a way to detect cross over of hands?

Tags: leap-motion

Is there a standard way of allowing two hands to cross each other with the Leap Motion API?

It seems that when I cross my hands, one hand is knocked out, until I uncross my hands in which the hand is reinserted into the environment but is assigned a new ID.

This even when using the debug tool built into the Leap Motion console.

Comment: There might not be a good solution to this. If one hand completely obscures the other from the sensor, it won't know the other is there. You might be able to use some heuristics in your code to deal with the situation where two hands approach one another, turn into one hand, then reappear as two, so that the "new" hand is associated with the one that was obscured and then returned into view..

Comment: I've also experienced the same behaviour; of the LeapMotion Controller losing track of one of my hands after I cross them. I've witnessed this in both the Diagnostic Visualizer and the Leap Motion Visualizer. Unfortunately, this seems to indicate that the data isn't being exposed via the API - that it's a bug/limitation and we'll have to hope that it get fixed in a future firmware release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to detect the cross over hands right now, as the shape of the cross over hands doesn't fit the 3D hand model adopted by the leap motion. This also happens when you have an object in your hand. The object is treated as a part of your hand and when this shape is compared to the 3D model, it produces random fitting results or fitting at all.

So, in short, no there is no way.